# RPi2, OpenMAX, Deadlock

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, raspberry-pi, openmax

### Environment

- Raspberry Pi 2 B+
- Debian Linux
- OpenMAX IL

### Use-case

- OpenMAX Camera Video capture

  - Camera ports are disabled
  - Renderer / Camera Tunnel is set
  - All components state is set to Idle
  - Ports are enabled

### Problem description

The first port being enabled to the Camera Input port ( Port #73 ), the port is being enabled using the “OMX_CommandPortEnable” command, as with the “OMX_CommandPortDisable” command, it is expected for the camera component to fire it’s “OMX_CALLBACKTYPE::EventHandler” event handler having “eEvent == OMX_EventCmdComplete” and “nData1 == OMX_CommandPortEnable”, however, this never happen and the application infinitely wait for the port to become enabled.

### Problem Analysis

I am using std::condition_variable in conjunction with std::mutex to wait for the state change to complete, hence, OMX_CALLBACKTYPE::EventHandler updates the condition variable and calls “notify_one()” while the caller thread locks std::mutex and wait for the condition variable to be set, using this approach “OMX_CALLBACKTYPE::EventHandler” is never called ( with any argument ), and the program locks forever.
**NOTE**: When waiting for the condition variable the mutex is verified not to be owned, this is done by verifying (0 == std::mutex::__owner).
**HOWEVER**, All works fine when polling the status of the port by calling usleep and OMX_GetParameter(OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition) iteratively.

### Question at hand

Why is “OMX_CALLBACKTYPE::EventHandler” triggered when polling it’s value and NOT triggered when using a conditional_variable? With windows there is the notion of APC & Alertable threads, is there any equivalent in linux? One that can explain the above mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that enabling a port does not issue the event callback until the port is populated with buffers. That is, the sequence is:

- Set port to enabled (`OMX_SendCommand()` with `OMX_CommandPortEnable`).
- Populate port buffers (`OMX_AllocateBuffer()` or `OMX_UseBuffer()`).
- Receive `OMX_CommandPortEnable` event callback.

If you wait for the event callback before you allocate the buffers then you will have deadlock.

When you poll by testing `OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE.bEnabled`, that is going to return `OMX_TRUE` immediately because [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/omxil/specs/OpenMAX_IL_1_1_2_Specification.pdf) says this member is set synchronously:

> The port shall immediately set `bEnabled` in its port definition
>   structure when the port receives `OMX_CommandPortEnable`.

Here's what I think is happening for you when things "work":

- Set port to enabled.
- Poll until `bEnabled` is `OMX_TRUE` (which happens immediately).
- Populate port buffers.
- Receive `OMX_CommandPortEnable` event callback.

You may be mistakenly thinking that it happens in this order instead:

- Set port to enabled.
- Poll until `bEnabled` is `OMX_TRUE` (which happens immediately).
- Receive `OMX_CommandPortEnable` event callback.
- Populate port buffers.

This makes it seem that using a condition variable somehow changes OpenMAX behavior. In actuality `bEnabled` and the `OMX_CommandPortEnable` callback aren't really reporting the same thing. I don't believe that any synchronization is necessary (or desirable) between enabling the port and allocating its buffers.